# How should I relocate drain lines as I remove a bathroom wall to make room for a larger bathtub?

Tags: plumbing, drain, vent, pvc

My wife and I have started on a project to renovate our master bath.  We're pretty comfortable on most home projects but moving around drain lines isn't something we have a ton of experience in so I'm hoping to get some direction about what we can or can't do ourselves.

We took out the built-in shower and are now hoping to knock out the wall the old fixtures were on to have more space for a tiled shower and tub.

I'm a little bit confused about what my options are for moving this plumbing around. Looking at this first picture:
[image: hot and cold supply lines, drains for tub and laundry in wall]

I'm thinking the drain from the laundry drain line could just go straight into the basement and have a P trap there (there's even a hole already drilled there as if the builder originally intended that).  The line in the middle of the picture is already within the wall, so I could cut out that bottom Tee and seal that off just fine I believe. Where I get more confused is that top tee and where it cuts over into the next picture:

[image: another angle showing supply and drain lines in same wall]

In this picture, I'm less sure about how to that line out of the back wall to connect to these drain lines. Can I do a corner fitting to turn it straight down fast enough so that it wouldn't extend beyond that 2x4 wall and then remove the higher cross piece and connect those only in the basement? Or is this more involved on how to make it all fit together to regain that space?

2 more pictures of that area as well as the basement access.

[image: closer angle of picture 2]
[image: pvc drain lines between joists in basement ceiling]

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are under IPC (or "as adopted" IPC) I'd suggest spending some time with chapters 7, 9, and 10, available online for free. If not, whatever code you are under. https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018P5/chapter-9-vents

Comment: For anyone to offer specific advice, we would have to know what your applicable plumbing code is, in your location. There's (at least) IPC, UPC, various state and city codes which may or may not be based more or less on one of those, or completely off in their own world. I can say that some of your ideas appear to miss the concept of venting, so give chapter 9 a good look even if that isn't your code - it will be similar, mostly, even if details differ.

Comment: Frankly that looks beyond the capability of a regular homeowner.  I'd let the professionals do it.

Comment: I can look at that.  Even if I hire a professional, I'd like to understand how it would be solved.  I like asking at places like this so I have the opportunity to learn.

Given the the drain line in the second to last picture has a rise, is it not going over to a vented drain line, given it is rising above the height of the sink in which the drain is for?

Comment: This pictures are a bit disjointed, but most likely that is, in fact, a vent line, not a drain line at all. And you were talking about stuffing it under the floor, which you can't do with a vent line - they need to go up. Most codes don't permit putting a laundry standpipe trap below the floor, either. Again, we'll need to know exactly what code applies, here, as they do vary.